# Removing double-encoded JSON values in PSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

Given a table in Postgresql, defined approximately as follows:

```
   Column    |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | character varying           | not null  | extended |              | 
 answers     | json                        |           | extended |              |
```

we accidentally did a number of inserts to this database of doubly-encoded JSON objects, ie the json value is a string, that is a json-encoded object -- for example:

`"{\"a\": 1}"`

We'd like to find a query that would convert these values to the JSON objects they represent, for example:

`{"a": 1}`

We can easily select the bad values by doing:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE json_type(answers) = 'string'`

but we are having trouble coming up with a way to parse the JSON in PSQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunaly, there is no string-extraction function for the `json[b]` type(s) directly, but you can workaround this by embedding the value inside a JSON array & using the `->>` operator for string extraction at the `0` array index:

```
UPDATE table
SET    answers = (CONCAT('[', answers::text, ']')::json ->> 0)::json
WHERE  json_type(answers) = 'string'
```

This should work with lower PostgreSQL versions too (9.3). For newer versions (9.4+), you could use the [`json_build_array()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) too.

Comment: LOL! I love this

Comment: Hero, you are a hero.